# How to configure Multichannel ADC properly? Currently two different values stored in same variable

Tags: adc, stm32, stm32f4-discovery

I want to use Multichannel ADC using the STM32F4 so I want to read two different AC signals on two different pins/channels. One AC signal value should be stored in ADCConvertedValue[0] and the other in ADCConvertedValue[1].

The problem is that both of the pins store their value in ADCConvertedValue[0]. I skipped the initialization code and put the important part below. Does someone see the problem?

```
  __IO uint16_t ADCConvertedValue[2]; 

  ADC_HandleTypeDef    AdcHandle;

  AdcHandle.Instance          = ADC2;
  AdcHandle.Init.ClockPrescaler        = ADC_CLOCKPRESCALER_PCLK_DIV4;
  AdcHandle.Init.Resolution            = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  AdcHandle.Init.ScanConvMode          = ENABLE;          
  AdcHandle.Init.ContinuousConvMode    = ENABLE;                      
  AdcHandle.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;                      
  AdcHandle.Init.NbrOfDiscConversion   = 0;
  AdcHandle.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge  = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;      
  AdcHandle.Init.DataAlign             = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  AdcHandle.Init.NbrOfConversion       = 2; 
  AdcHandle.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
  AdcHandle.Init.EOCSelection          = EOC_SEQ_CONV;

  sConfig.Channel      = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
  sConfig.Rank         = 1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_480CYCLES; 

  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&AdcHandle, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sConfig.Channel      = ADC_CHANNEL_2;
  sConfig.Rank         = 2;

  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&AdcHandle, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

 if(HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&AdcHandle, (uint32_t*)&ADCConvertedValue, 2) != HAL_OK) 
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
```

Comment: I think you left out the important part of the code - where you read the ADC and store the result.

Comment: I've added some more code, the last code starts the conversion process and stores results in ADCConvertedValue and I've indicated the number 2 but somehow it doesn't work.

Comment: How have you determine that both values are stored in ADCConvertedValue[0]?

Comment: In the Live Watch window I see the array ADCConvertedValue and then I can expand it by clicking the + button and then I see ADCConvertedValue[0] and ADCConvertedValue[1] both in different locations obviously.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you solved the problem, but as I see, you need to change

```
AdcHandle.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SEQ_CONV;
```

to

```
AdcHandle.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
```

Because, `ADC_EOC_SEQ_CONV` flag is rised after the all conversions are ended (all channels passed), but you need move data from the ADC to the memory after each conversion, so use `ADC_EOC_SEQ_CONV`.

If it doesn't help, can you please post your DMA configuration?

Comment: About the last line, I think you mean: "so use `ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV`."